# Jquery not capturing input second time after ajax return

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this modal, which I am using the edit the value of field named "newValue". When I submit the form, the jquery captures the new value correctly (let's say edit some value to aaa). But, when I submit the form again, after getting the first return from ajax, (let's say edit another value to bbb), the value is still captured as aaa.

The form:

```
<form class="formEditDataTemplateField" data-validate="parsley" style="margin: 0;" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://localhost" method="POST">
    <div>
        Edit "Data-field" to
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="Add1" style="width: 200px; margin-bottom: 2px" placeholder="Enter Data-field" required="required" id="newValue" name="newValue" class="form-control">
    </div>                

    <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="javascript:$('.formEditData').parsley('validate');" class="btn btn-primary" name="send">      
</form>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $('form.formEditDataTemplateField').on('submit', function()
    {       
        var to =  $('#newValue').val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'my-url',
            data:
            {  
                to: to,
                action: 'edit'

            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
            {
                if($.trim(response) == "true")
                {
                    alert("success")
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("failed")                    
                }
            }
        });

        return false;  

    })
})
```

**Added Info:**

I have 2 links on the page ("aaa" and "bbb"), each of which are using the same bootstrap modal to edit the link value with the new value that will be entered in the modal text box. So I click "aaa", enter "aaa1" in the modal, update using ajax and on return success REFRESH the page. Then i click "bbb", enter "bbb1" and try to update, the value captured by jquery $('#newValue').val(); is "aaa1". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have created this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bFeFF/ . Can you please reproduce the issue there. I donot see any issue.

Comment: @APaul the problem occurs only after the return from ajax, how to reproduce that?

Comment: Do you have this on a website currently thats not localhost? @nsk

Comment: @JochemQuery no, don't have it live anywhere. I am not sure if this is a cache issue, or bootstrap modal or ... :|

Comment: I have edited the question and added some details. hope that helps to explain.

Comment: it looks like there is something not really refreshing, even you have set cache false, that cache is maybe doing something. Maybe if you step trough it in chrome/firefox console you can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. Adding this line before my form selector solved the problem:

```
$(document).off("submit", "form.formEditDataTemplateField");
```